# Memory access only possible with stack registers after switching to 32-bit compat mode, in an x86-64 Linux process that started as 64-bit

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, memory-segmentation

After trying to switch an x86-64 linux process to 32 bit compatibility mode with an `lret`, we can't access memory except when addressing with ESP or EBP.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Example:

```
.text
.global _start

.code64
_start:

movl $0x23, 4(%rsp)
leal start32, %eax
movl %eax, (%rsp)
lretl // jmp to start32 and change mode to 32 bit

.code32
start32:

leal value, %esp
movl (%esp), %eax // works

leal value, %ebp
movl (%ebp), %eax // works

//leal value, %eax
//movl (%eax), %eax // segfault

//leal value, %ebx
//movl (%ebx), %eax // segfault

//leal value, %ecx
//movl (%ecx), %eax // segfault

//leal value, %edx
//movl (%edx), %eax // segfault

//leal value, %esi
//movl (%esi), %eax // segfault

//leal value, %edi
//movl (%edi), %eax // segfault

//movl value, %eax // segfault

movl $1, %eax // 32 bit style exit
movl $0, %ebx
int $128

.data

value:
  .long 0x1337
```

Comment: All instructions that access memory use a default/implied segment register (unless it's overridden by a segment override prefix). All of your instructions that work use `SS` as the default segment register; and all of the instructions that crash use `DS` as the default segment register. With this in mind, whatever random trash Linux happened to leave in `DS` (which is ignored in 64-bit code) is likely not valid for 32-bit code.

Comment: @Brendan: Linux sets DS = ES = FS = GS = 0 (the null selector) in 64-bit mode.  If you try to mov some random value into DS, the CPU faults even in 64-bit mode, but maybe you meant random trash left in the internal segment base/limit/etc state registers.  (And yes, SS=0x2b on my Linux system, from a quick `gdb /bin/ls` / `starti`)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes - can probably work around it by loading the value from SS into DS (and ES); and then you can expect it to break anyway, either because low level signal handling (in a 64-bit shared library) can't work, or because thread local variables can't work, or because ASLR put stuff at a "too high" address, or something else. Better would be to realize it wasn't intended to work and just use `exec()` to start a 32-bit executable.

Comment: @Brendan: Yeah, I doubt it's intended to be supported; it's a fun entry in the catalogue of silly computer tricks, though.  And an interesting exploration into where Linux makes assumptions about things like segment registers.  (e.g. can you get into the kernel and back with an `int 0x80` system call from a task/thread that started in 64-bit mode, or will that return with CS = 64-bit user-space CS?  Good point about POSIX signal handlers if you registered any with `sigaction`; that might well use a 64-bit CS.)

Comment: Linux does have `modify_ldt` to create your own segment entries, but maybe not intended for stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks, setting `es` and `ds` to the value of `ss` indeed solves these segfaults. We are aware that this is hacky and unsupported of course. We are currently exploring the space of possibilities for a size coding challenge.

Comment: @rgba: Ah - exploring is fun. For code size; note that if you wrote 32-bit assembly source code and assembled it into 64-bit machine code; almost all of it will be identical and the only likely difference will be that a few `inc` and `dec` instructions will use a different/larger encoding. I'd be a little bit skeptical that the "`inc`/`dec` savings" would cover the cost of extra  instructions needed to switch to 32-bit compatibility mode. The main size reduction is using 32-bit addresses/pointers, which can be done in 64-bit code anyway (I think it's the default if you don't compile as PIE).

Comment: @Brendan I have not yet checked which instructions become larger when using the 32 bit part of the registers in 64 bit mode, but some of the code needs exactly double-word operations. Another huge advantage is the availability of pusha/popa that is essentially a single byte context switch (and nearly all registers are in use)! We will have a deeper look into it again how large the difference actually s but it seems like the mode change pays off.